# Writing Unit Test for Service Response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, frontend

I'm trying to unit test an API in my ngOnInit method. The method makes a call to the service to retrieve details - if the details aren't undefined, an array of type *shoeData [] called 'shoeDataResponse' will be populated with these details and return the response.

*shoeDataResponse: shoeData[];

here is the method:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shoeService.getShoeData().subscribe((shoeDetails) => {
      if (shoeDetails != undefined) {
        this.shoeDataResponse = shoeDetails;
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is even the correct apporach but here's what I tried in the spec file:

```
  it('should return data if defined',  waitForAsync(() => { 
let shoeDataResponse = [
      {
        mCompanyIDEntity: {
          mbranchID: '108020',
          misShippingItem: true,
          mIsBranchNumber: false,
        },
        companyName: 'SOME COMPANY',
        shoeBalance: 1250.00,
        orderDate: '',
        mAccountHolder: false,
      },
    ];

    spyOn(ShoeService, 'getShoeData').and.returnValue(of(shoeDataResponse));
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

When running the test I get an error saying,  "Argument of type '"getShoeData"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prototype"'.

so yeah all help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the way you are setting up the spy for `getShoeData`. You have to create a spy on the *instance* of the service that is injected into the component instead of directly spying on the service class.

First create the instance of the service:

```
  let shoeService: ShoeService; // initialize the instance

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ComponentName],
      providers: [ShoeService], // add the service in the providers
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    shoeService = TestBed.inject(ShoeService); // add this line to create an instance of ShoeService
  });
```

Then, in your test, spy on the `shoeService` instance instead of the `ShoeService` class method

```
spyOn(shoeService, 'getShoeData').and.returnValue(of(shoeDataResponse));
```